What is the IC marked as 858Z TI 31JP7J3 (can see the photo attached)?
Can anyone help me with this ic code written on the smd component

Hi! In such cases, the context usually is necessary to help you: what is the purpose of the chip, what device is it from, what are the surrounding components? Is it in any specific section of the board?

It's a Texas Instruments DAC80508ZRT 8 channel DAC.


(Source: avaq.com)

Thank you @nanash1, i was expecting DAC due to the nature of the circuit. But one doubt, how did you searched or what was your keyword because even now when i'm searching in your referenced source website it is not showing this device.?

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac80508.pdf is the datasheet on the TI website, which is revision SLASEL1D revised August 2018, which is later than SLASEL1C revised April 2018 which is linked in the answer. The later revision has completed the Eco Plan, Lead finish/Ball material and MSL Peak Temp columns, which are "TBD" or "Call TI" in the picture in the answer.

@Meet DAC80508 True 16-bit, 8-channel, SPI, voltage-output DAC with precision internal reference is the manufacturers (TI) product page for the device.

@Meet I google searched texas instruments "858Z" marking. The datasheet is the first result.

https://www.ti.com/packaging/en/docs/partlookup.tsp?partmarking=858z
